# low write disk speed of windows kvm guest with LVM

Tags: raid, kvm-virtualization, lvm, qemu

I have a trouble with my windows 2008 R2 KVM guest. It write speed to disk extremely slow: [image] 
But on another VM (windows 10) on this KVM host write speed is ok:
[image]

```
# cat /etc/system-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 
# virsh -V
Virsh command line tool of libvirt 1.2.8
See web site at http://libvirt.org/

Compiled with support for:
 Hypervisors: QEMU/KVM LXC ESX Test
 Networking: Remote Network Bridging Interface netcf Nwfilter VirtualPort
 Storage: Dir Disk Filesystem SCSI Multipath iSCSI LVM Gluster
 Miscellaneous: Daemon Nodedev SELinux Secrets Debug DTrace Readline Modular
# qemu-system-x86_64 -version
QEMU emulator version 2.0.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Slow VM XML configuration:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='24'>
  <name>SLOW-VM</name>
  <uuid>405f55de-ee46-7d1a-4915-a82b617f5706</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vg/slow-vm'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='floppy'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vg/slow-vm-2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='fda' bus='fdc'/>
      <alias name='fdc0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='fdc' index='0'>
      <alias name='fdc0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5901' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1' keymap='en-us'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='16384' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Another VM XML configuration:

```
<domain type='kvm' id='21'>
  <name>vm</name>
  <uuid>e48f03ad-aced-452b-9e85-904ee5be61cb</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-1.5'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>cpu64-rhel6</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='nx'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vg/vm'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='hdd' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='ide0-1-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <alias name='usb0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/4'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/4'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/4'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5903' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1' keymap='en-us'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='16384' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I try to use cache = 'none' and io = 'native' - without result.
I try to change emulator and machine type on the slow VM - without result.

lsblk:

```
sdd                               8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk   
|-sdd1                            8:49   0   500M  0 part   
| `-md0                           9:0    0 499.7M  0 raid1  /boot
`-sdd2                            8:50   0   931G  0 part   
  `-md1                           9:1    0   1.8T  0 raid10 
    |-vg-slowvm                 253:0    0    180G  0 lvm   
    |-vg-vm                     253:13   0    24G  0 lvm
```

Where is misconfiguration?

Comment: Given that one guest works fine and the other doesn't, I'd start by looking at what is different between the *guests*, not what the host looks like.

Comment: Yes, I understand.

different's:
- windows 2008R2 vs windows 10 (32 and 64 bit);
- cache. I try to change it - without result;
- emulator and machine type. I try to change it - without result;

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on the virtio driver on the slow Windows guest.
I have change it to the bus=scsi. + I set on the KVM host profile: virtual-host via adm-tune.

[image]

Comment: It is very interesting. From my own experience virtio is faster and more reliable that scsi in windows guests. I never used CentOS as host, probably they have a regression in this release. It probably worth submitting a bug report to them...

Comment: VirtIO (passphru) storage access is usually much faster than any of the emulations. The same goes for ethernet devices. So your case is strange at least. That looks like a bug in your guest VirtIO driver.

Comment: Yes you are right, usually virtio the fastest, but in this case I think something wrong with virtio driver inside slow VM. As you can see on the other vm  (windows 10) I use virtio and write speed faster. I don't now how to delete virtio driver from windows, and fastest solution of the problem was a change bus type.